# Android studio not creating the activity_main.xml file and not even the layout?

Tags: android-studio

While creating a new project in android studio, the layout file under the res directory is not showing at all. Neither the layout nor the activity_main.xml file is showing

[image: Image1]

In this the layout file and the activity_main.xml file is there which I created few days back.

[image: Image2]

But when creating a new project now, there is no presence of the layout and the activity_main.xml file.

Comment: What type of project are you creating? If it is a Jetpack Compose activity, there won't be any layout file since in Jetpack Compose you build the layout programmatically.

Comment: Yeah !! was doing doing that mistake only. Thank you so much for helping.